# Insert into a map as a field of map in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to create a struct, one of whose fields is a map. However, I cannot initialize it with a method and then insert a value with another method. It reports error

> panic: assignment to entry in nil map

Coming from a Python background, I am confused on what I missed.

Here is the goal playground [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/Vp3vl9Ow41)

```
package main

type profile map[string]float64

type foobar struct {
    foo profile
    bar map[string]profile
}

func (fb foobar) Init() {
    fb.foo = make(profile)
    fb.bar = make(map[string]profile)
}

func (fb foobar) Set() {
    fb.bar["foo1"] = make(profile)
}

func main() {
    test := foobar{}
    test.Init()
    test.Set()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Init` method receiver `(fb foobar)` is a value. It should be a pointer `(fb *foobar)`. For example,

```
package main

type profile map[string]float64

type foobar struct {
    foo profile
    bar map[string]profile
}

func (fb *foobar) Init() {
    fb.foo = make(profile)
    fb.bar = make(map[string]profile)
}

func (fb foobar) Set() {
    fb.bar["foo1"] = make(profile)
}

func main() {
    test := foobar{}
    test.Init()
    test.Set()
}
```

Reference:

[Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for pointing me to the right literature!